# How to check if a named table exists or not in ETS Erlang/Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

I want to create a table in ets if it does not exists . How can I check if this named exists or not ?

Comment: I recommend to create it in try..catch expression.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`:ets.whereis/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#whereis-1). It will return `:undefined` if the named table does not exist:

```
iex(1)> :ets.new :foo, [:named_table]
:foo
iex(2)> :ets.whereis :foo
#Reference<0.2091350666.119668737.256142>
iex(3)> :ets.whereis :bar
:undefined
```

Comment: iex(14)> :ets.new :foo, [:named_table]
:foo
iex(15)> :ets.whereis :foo
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :ets.whereis/1 is undefined or private
    (stdlib) :ets.whereis(:foo)

Comment: What version of Erlang are you on? You can also try `:ets.info(:foo)`.

Comment: `ets:whereis` was introduced in Erlang/OTP 21.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on an older version of Erlang, you can create a lookup function:

```
def lookup(server, name) do
  case :ets.lookup(server, name) do
    [{^name, pid}] -> {:ok, pid}
    [] -> :error
  end
end
```

Information taken from:  https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/ets.html

Comment: This will raise a `badarg` error if the table doesn't exist.

Comment: Yep.  That is true.

Answer (score 1):

Your best best is just to see if the table is in the list of all tables.  A check as simple as this should be good:

```
lists:member(table_name,ets:all())
```

This returns a simple boolean() that you can use in a case to base actions on.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

> ```
> def create_table? do 
>   if Enum.member?(:ets.all(), :my_table) == false do
>       :ets.new(:my_table, [:public, :named_table])
>   end
> end
> ```